Inconsistance Product's Variation Order In Drupal
Currently i am using drupal 9.5 with Commerce Core 8.x-2.38. I am trying to list product with its variation in the order set in product variation. But strangely, the view is not loading the product variation in correct order everytime for some product only. If i manually go and change the product variation , then it will show me correct order but its hampering other product variation order which was correct before.
Its strange that i am getting inconsistance product variation order for same view query with no changes.
Please help me guys.

cache? did you try to clean it out?

otherwise debug.

Seems by default product variation are not loaded in the sequence order so we can use Product:Variation(Variation:delta) in sorting criteria in the view and sort production variation as asc. It resolved the issue.

